# Wordpress Rewrite Rule to enforce default lang code in URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, qtranslate

I am running a WP Blog with qtranslate. It allows me to create posts in multiple languages.

1 . Example URL without qtranslate:

- [www.mysite.com/post1](http://www.mysite.com/post1)

2 . Example URL with localized content:

- [www.mysite.com/**en**/post1](http://www.mysite.com/**en**/post1) (english - my default and fallback)
- [www.mysite.com/**de**/post1](http://www.mysite.com/**de**/post1)

Unfortunately search engines etc. still remember my old links (1.) and these are still access-able. So "www.mysite.com/post1" now shows my english content without a redirect. But what it *should* do is to 301 users to "www.mysite.com/en/post1".

So now I would need a rule that basically checks if there is /**en**/post1 or a /**de**/post1 in the URL and otherwise redirect to the fallback /**en**/post1 URL. There is one exception because "/**shop**" is a real subdirectory and does not need to be preceeded by language information.

-- UPDATE --

I did it!!! That was actually fun but took me quite a while to figure out.

```
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/{1}$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{3,})(/|$)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are probably better ways to do this but it does the trick. Thanks everyone for the initial help!

Comment: Looking for "en", "de", etc. looks like a bad idea, it could be hard to mantain. You already have one exception, more may come, and it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Camilo, you are right. It is not pretty - I just simply don´t know enough about Rewrites to make it work properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a universal RewriteRule, and using RewriteConds to eliminate the cases that you don't want it to rewrite?

It would go something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301]
```

But as per Camilo's suggestion, you could change that middle line to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}(/|$)
```

as long as you can ensure that your post permalinks won't be less than three characters (I'm not familiar enough with WordPress to be sure if that's possible).

Comment: Rick, thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn´t mix well with the existing WP redirects and breaks the site. There are already some cond in there and adding your code conflicts with them. 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^en/$ en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^de/$ de [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I am thinking something along the lines of: RewriteRule !^/(en|de)(/|$) /en/$1 [R=301,L] This causes a redirect loop though but it should *something* like that...

Answer (score 0):

What about just using meta canonical?

Like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

More info: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: Great idea but it is still recommended by Google to serve content just from one URL. Kind of hard but with a few fixes it works. Also it seems most logical in my own view. Just needed to dig into these Rules myself to really understand how to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!!! That was actually fun but took me quite a while to figure out.

```
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/{1}$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{3,})(/|$)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are probably better ways to do this but it does the trick

-- UPDATE this includes support for longer URLs ---

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{3,}(/|$).*)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```