# Redirect (web.config) rule to enforce subdirectory

Tags: .net, web-config

Our site uses "subfolders" for specifying languages (e.g. www.domain.com/nl or www.domain.com/en). The default language is Dutch (nl). Currently visitors are both able to visit pages via the specified language (e.g. www.domain.com/nl) or the root domain (e.g. www.domain.com).

For SEO purposes we want to redirect (enforce) all users visiting the root to the specificed language (nl) (e.g. www.domain.com/page/1 to www.domain.com/nl/page/1).

Previous approaches (using web.config rewrite rule) led to (infinite) loops (e.g. www.domain.com/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/nl/etc.).

I know this topic [Rewrite Rule to enforce default lang code in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220869/rewrite-rule-to-enforce-default-lang-code-in-url) describes how to do it in .htaccess, but I don't have a clue how to convert it to web.config.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: so you want all the users who enter www.dowmain.com/page/1 will be redirected to www.domain.com/nl/page/1  ?

Comment: @ISHIDA Correct. And www.domain.com/sub/sub/sub to www.domain.com/nl/sub/sub/sub. So always enforce the language sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <configuration>
           <system.webServer>
             <rewrite>
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" /> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/install/" negate="true" /> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/nl/" negate="true" /> 
</conditions>
            <rules>   
             <rule name="Language" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^/nl" negate="true" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/nl/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
            </rewrite>
            </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
```

The above rule will redirect all www.domain.com/sub/sub to www.domain.com/nl/sub/sub

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not working. Tried this before.
When visiting for example domain.com/page, it doesn't redirect to domain.com/nl/page, but to domain.com/nl instead.

Comment: Results in an inifinite loop (e.g. /nl/nl/nl/nl/nl)

Comment: Got it working using these conditions. Thanks!    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
   <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
   <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/install/" negate="true" />
   <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/nl/" negate="true" />